# Making typesafe auto load modules container in Awilix Typescript

Tags: typescript, awilix

I'm using [Awilix](https://github.com/jeffijoe/awilix) with Typescript. This is how I'm creating `container`

```
const container = createContainer();

container.loadModules(["src/service/**/*.ts"], {
  formatName: "camelCase",

  resolverOptions: {
    injectionMode: InjectionMode.CLASSIC,
    register: asClass,
  },
});
```

There is only one service `helloWorldService` but creating container like this will not provide any safety. For example I can do this `container.cradle.someBadThing` typescript will not give me any error.

The only way I found is to create manually interface.

```
interface ICradle {
  helloWorldService: HelloWorldService;
}
const container = createContainer<ICradle>();
```

This works fine but problem is if you have 100's of file and you have to mention each file in `interface` can get boring. How we can automate this thing?